# Should we use EventQueue.invokeLater for any GUI update in a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

I know that by using this method, the runnable parameter is submitted to the system EventQueue.
But should all GUI updates be done this using this method? I mean, if i want to say, change a text of JButton, should i use something like this:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         jButton1.setText("changed text");
      }
});
```

If i should use this approach, any pattern we can use to avoid this repetitive code?

Comment: Note: slow code needs to go there too to keep swing responsive

Comment: @nash If any of the answers below answers your question, could you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 27):

You only need to use [`invokeLater`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) when you want to update your UI from another thread that is not the UI thread (event dispatch thread).

Suppose you have a handler for a button-click and you want to change the text of a label when someone clicks the button. Then it's perfectly save to set the label text directly. This is possible because the handler for the button-click event runs in the UI thread.

Suppose, however, that on another button-click you start *another* thread that does some work and after this work is finished, you want to update the UI. Then you use `invokeLater`. This method ensures that your UI update is executed on the UI thread.

So in a lot of cases, you do not need `invokeLater`, you can simply do UI updates directly. If you're not sure, you can use [`isDispatchThread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread()) to check whether your current code is running inside the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Ok, i guess, if we are not sure, we can use EventQueue.isDispatchThread() method to check if current thread is event dispatch thread. right?

Comment: That's correct. I added some info about this method to my answer.

Comment: But there's still no shortcut?   I would sure have liked a shortcut or a macro for the above boilerplate (if isDispatchThread do X, otherwise wrap X and pend it.).   Coming from Delphi I would like to call the whole thing `Sync( x(a,b,c) )` but I guess with java syntax being java syntax, the `public void {}` stuff is unavoidable.  It's funny to me that I should find myself wishing for C-style macros to avoid writing Java as it's designed to be written.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this only if you're not already on the event dispatch thread. Unless you've started new threads or executed code from the main thread all your code probably already runs from the event dispatch thread making this unnecessary. For example, all the UI event handlers are called on the event dispatch thread so you would not need to do that for code called from there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of truly avoiding "repetitive" (java people would probably say, readable code without many secrets) you could use Eclipse's templates feature. i have it set to expand the two letters "il" to the following block:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // do something.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Apparently this dispatch queue design is not only recommended, it's basically required.   This is perhaps the noisiest way I've ever seen in any language of pushing a lambda off into a message queue. But there it is.  This is java.  And in Java's defence, it's certainly obvious from the above exactly what's going on.  I do resent the amount of typing, but the only thing I can think of that would avoid it is C preprocessor Macros, and I bet Java people don't like using those. Code expansion via templates is more readable, supportable, and doesn't involve any black magic.

Comment: P no, not, never use try - catch - finally for build the GUI, nor inside invokeLater :-)

Comment: @mKorbel can you explain why?

Comment: I think you have no choice for checked exceptions.