# java eventqueue

Tags: java, multithreading

is this procedure going to execute in separate thread?

```
class Counter extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0;isCounting;i++) {
                    try {Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);} 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    setTitle(""+i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it is a part of class which extends JFrame. now, if i start an instance of this class somewhere in the constructor of JFrame extending class, will it run in the separate thread, or in the EDT? because i tried it, and obviously it runs in EDT because the program stuck...

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541373/should-we-use-eventqueue-invokelater-for-any-gui-update-in-java-desktop-applicati and this http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling Java to run that on the EDT when you use EventQueue.invokeLater.

For more on this, please see this tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)