# Why does my boilerplate Java desktop app JFrame use EventQueue.invokeLater in the main method?

Tags: java, swing

I am using the latest Eclipse, and GWT Designer, to make a swing application in Java.
The main function in my application window (which is a javax.swing.JFrame) in the auto generated by the tools looks like this:

```
    /* launch the application */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AppWindow window = new AppWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This seems like a lot of noise around what could have been just this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                AppWindow window = new AppWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


}
```

I have read that the EventQueue.InvokeLater technique is required in some situations, and another question asks where to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541373/should-we-use-eventqueue-invokelater-for-any-gui-update-in-java-desktop-applicati).

My question is simpler; Why do this automatically in the code generator here? Why should main return quickly and let the application window get created later by the event queue?  Wouldn't blocking be exactly the point?  Why is the JFrame auto-generated designer doing this EventQueue stuff?   I have tried to see some difference in the start up and showing of forms whether this code is done the simpler way or the harder way, and I can only conclude provisionally that this has some benefits that are not visible in tiny demo apps made by beginners like me, and that perhaps in real-world large complex Jframe based classes, there is some benefit to this delaying/queuing strategy?

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156949/main-thread-vs-ui-thread-in-java/7158505#7158505).

Comment: Since it seems that I'll need it lots, I made a template in eclipse to put this boilerplate eventqueue stuff easily into code. il and then control-space, expands to the whole mess above.

Comment: I use a similar approach in NetBeans.

Comment: it's not about "quickly leaving main", it's about pushing the creation onto the EDT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your application and how it's being used, it's possible that there could be something that is drawing on the screen (and thus using the `EventQueue`) before or during the call to your `main` method. Calls that modify any UI components should be made on the `Event Dispatch Thread`, and this includes setting the application visible.

So just to be safe, it's a good practice to start your application on the `EDT`.

> Why do this automatically in the code generator here?

It won't hurt, it's easy to generate, and it's considered good practice.

> Why should main return quickly and let the application window get created later by the event queue?

It's possible that the `main` method is being called from some other application that is using the `EDT` and may have already drawn something on screen. If you draw your application directly in `main`, it's possible that your application may be altering some component that is in the process of being handled by something on the `EDT`, and potentially already drawn on the screen.

So just to be safe in case this situation ever happens, you should leave it up to the `EDT` to draw your application so it can do it when it won't interfere with anything else.

> Wouldn't blocking be exactly the point?

Unless something else is calling `main` other than the JVM process that your user started by double-clicking the desktop icon, it's not going to make a difference when `main` returns as long as there is something on the screen.

> I can only conclude provisionally that this has some benefits that are not visible in tiny demo apps made by beginners like me

You're right - most of the time it's probably not gonna make a difference, but I presume they included it because it was easy to generate & implement, it can't hurt, and it would exemplify good practice.

Answer (score 2):

1) why is building Swing GUI inside try-catch-finally, I can't see any reason(s) for that, split create non thread safe GUI and non thread safe code to the separates threads,

2) Swing isn't thread safe, then correct is in all cases that `pack() + setVisible(true)` would be

- last GUI rellated code lines
- wrapped into invokeLater
- forgot for examples from some code ExamplesDepots, this forum, another forums, sure these code works, but with risk that whatever/everything could happen
- correct Swing GUI launch

for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AppWindow window = new AppWindow();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);            
        }
    });
  }
```

3) is there some Serializable, [Custom L&F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) then (better would be) wrap into invokeAndWait