# Display JMS message from MDB to a view(JSF, SWING Applet or whatever)

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

I'm currently developing a JMS system. I have been able to develop the publisher (JSF), the subscriber (MDB) and I can print the JMS messages to the console from the `onMessage` method of the MDB.

My problem is that I can't manage to display them in a view: Either JSF, Applet or JTextArea swing.

How can I invoke the JTextArea of a given applet from the onMessage method of the MDB? I have tried to instantiate an Applet object from the MDB

ex: `TestApplet tst = new TestApplet()`:
Then into the `onMessage` method, after having extracted the message into `testMessage` variable I tried: `tst.textAtrea.append(testMessage);`

Here I got an error from the container.

Beside the above example, I would appreciate any other solution to my problem (just want to display the JMS messages in a view, not only at the console)

Comment: When you add the mdb tag, it gets translated to ms-access.  I think you intended message-driven-bean instead so changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to invoke a part of applet from MDB. Message will not be consumed till onMessage method is executed successfully. I would rather try to put the message in the some storage system (files or databases) and then display from these resources.

Comment: Hmmm..., i already thought about it but that might cause some delays in a scenario of real time data distribution. I'm working on my diploma thesis and it is a concern for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really use MDBs together with a Swing client in your scenario.

Instead

- Remove the MDB
- Implement a stand-alone command-line Swing client to listen on the queue directly.
- If you use a `MessageListener` in your Swing application, you will have an `onMessage` method there as well.
- Anyway you have to pay attention to the way you update Swing components from another thread: You can find the details here: [Should we use EventQueue.invokeLater for any GUI update in a Java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541425/2390083)

Any other client type (JSF, applet) will be more difficult.