# Assigning an Image object causes nothing to be drawn

Tags: java, image, graphics, drawing

I have it set up so all it does is draw a light gray background and some rectangles to create a grid. My next goal was to assign two images so I can default the grid to load as one, and then eventually add some listeners to let me change them to the other.

However, when I assign the image (png format) to the Image object through an ImageIcon (created and assigned previously and creating a new one on the spot were tested) it causes the default background color to be shown, and nothing drawn.

This occurs no matter where I move the assignments to except if I put the assignment into the draw method itself.

The image that I'm trying to use works fine, I pulled it straight from a previously working project, the location hadn't changed. But to be sure, I copied the address and put it in again.

Here is the code (The assignment causing the issue is in Block):

Main:

```
package BLURGpackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame
{
private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1200, FRAME_HEIGHT = 1034; // add 34 onto height  
//to show all of the panel

public Main()
{
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

    Panel panel = new Panel();

    add(panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m = new Main();
}
}
```

Panel:

```
package BLURGpackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
public final static int PANEL_WIDTH = 1200, PANEL_HEIGHT = 1000;
private Dimension panelDimension = new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);

private Thread panelThread = null;
private boolean threadRunning = false;

private Image dbi = null;
private Graphics dbg = null;

Grid grid;  

private int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
// ============ CHANGE THESE TO CHANGE THE LOCATION OF WHERE THE X AND Y COORDS ARE PRINTED ON THE SCREEN =============
private int printXCoordsX = 10; // X-Coordinate for where to print the current mouse X location
private int printXCoordsY = 855; // Y-Coordinate for where to print the current mouse X location
private int printYCoordsX = printXCoordsX; // X-Coordinate for where to print the current mouse Y location
private int printYCoordsY = printXCoordsY + 15; // Y-Coordinate for where to print the current mouse Y location
// ====================================================================================================================

public Panel()
{   
    grid = new Grid();

    setPreferredSize(panelDimension);
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);


    // ===== Listeners ==========
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
        }
    });

    // ====== Start ============= (if startPanel is before listeners, dbi is null... dunno why)
    startPanel();
}

private void startPanel()
{
    if(panelThread == null || threadRunning == false)
    {
        panelThread = new Thread(this);
        threadRunning = true;
        panelThread.start();
    }
    else
        System.out.println("panelThread is NOT null on startup");
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while(threadRunning)
    {
        update();
        render();
        paintScreen();
    }
}

public void update()
{
    // Logic here
}

public void render()
{
    if(dbi == null)
    {
        dbi = createImage(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        if(dbi == null)
            System.err.println("dbi is NULL");
        else
        {
            dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
        }
    }

    dbg.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    draw(dbg);
}

public void paintScreen()
{
    Graphics g;

    try
    {
        g = this.getGraphics();
        if(dbi != null && g != null)
        {
            g.drawImage(dbi, 0, 0, null);
        }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("X: "+mouseX, printXCoordsX, printXCoordsY);
    g.drawString("Y: "+mouseY, printYCoordsX, printYCoordsY);
    // Allow the Grid to draw
    grid.draw(g);
}
}
```

Grid:

```
package BLURGpackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Grid 
{
// ======== CHANGE THESE VARIABLES TO CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE GRID =============
public final static int GRID_ROWS = 21, GRID_COLUMNS = 25;
private final int RECT_WIDTH = 48, RECT_HEIGHT = 40;
private final int NUM_BLOCKS = GRID_ROWS*GRID_COLUMNS;

/*public final static int GRID_ROWS = 25, GRID_COLUMNS = 25;
private final int RECT_WIDTH = Panel.PANEL_WIDTH / GRID_ROWS; // 1200 / 25 = 48 px width per rect
private final int RECT_HEIGHT = Panel.PANEL_HEIGHT / GRID_COLUMNS; // 1000 / 25 = 40 px height per rect
private final int NUM_BLOCKS = GRID_ROWS*GRID_COLUMNS;*/
// ============================================================================

private Block[] blockArray;
private int[] blockSelectArray; // numbers for which block is selected. Feed in through file reader

public Grid()
{
    // ===== FOR TESTING ONLY======
    blockArray = new Block[NUM_BLOCKS];
    blockSelectArray = new int[NUM_BLOCKS];

    for(int i=0; i < NUM_BLOCKS; i++)
        {
            blockSelectArray[i] = 0;
        }
    // ============================

    loadBlocks();
}

private void loadBlocks()
{
    int x, y;
    x = y = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BLOCKS; i++)
    {
        if(x >= Panel.PANEL_WIDTH) // if x hits right boundary, reset x and increment y by the px height of a single block
        {
            x = 0;
            y += RECT_HEIGHT;
        }

        blockArray[i] = new Block(blockSelectArray[i], x, y);

        x += RECT_WIDTH;
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_BLOCKS;i++)
    {
        g.drawRect(blockArray[i].getBlockX(), blockArray[i].getBlockY(), RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
        blockArray[i].draw(g);
    }
}


}
```

Block:

```
package BLURGpackage;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Block 
{
private Image blockImage = null;
private Image DIRT_IMG = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Tyler/workspace/IntTut1/src/thejavahub/images/dirt.png").getImage();
// ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ Problem assignment
private Rectangle blockRect = null;
private boolean solid;

private final int RECT_WIDTH = Panel.PANEL_WIDTH / Grid.GRID_ROWS; // 1200 / 25 = 48 px width per rect
private final int RECT_HEIGHT = Panel.PANEL_HEIGHT / Grid.GRID_COLUMNS; // 1000 / 25 = 40 px height per rect

public Block(int blockNum, int x, int y)
{
    // switch statement on blockNum for what block
    switch(blockNum)
    {
    default:
        System.out.println("Default of switch in Block constrcutor hit");
        break;
    case 0: // background block

        solid = false;
        break;
    case 1: // dirt block 
        blockImage = DIRT_IMG; // <---- uses the assigned image --------
        solid = true;
        break;
    }
    // set the coordinates of the block
    blockRect = new Rectangle(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    // draw the image here (.... g.drawImage(blockImage, blockRect.x, blockRect.y, null);   )
    g.drawImage(blockImage, blockRect.x, blockRect.y, null);
}



// ==== GETTERS AND SETTERS ===
public int getBlockX()
{
    return this.blockRect.x;
}

public void setBlockX(int x)
{
    this.blockRect.x = x;
}

public int getBlockY()
{
    return this.blockRect.y;
}

public void setBlockY(int y)
{
    this.blockRect.y = y;
}


public boolean isSolid() {
    return solid;
}


public void setSolid(boolean solid) {
    this.solid = solid;
}




}
```

Comment: what is your actual question? What is not working?

Comment: First call `setVisible(true);` in the end after adding all the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some Points:

1. Call `frame.setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the components.
2. Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.
3. Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` in case of custom painting.
4. Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of Thread that is most suitable for swing application in two ways:

   - To perform a task once, after a delay.
   - To perform a task repeatedly.

     Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
5. Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

   Read more

   - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
   - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
   - [Should we use EventQueue.invokeLater for any GUI update in a Java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541373/should-we-use-eventqueue-invokelater-for-any-gui-update-in-a-java-desktop-applic)

sample code:

```
private Timer timer;
...

// 1 second delay
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // next call
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main m = new Main();
        }
    });
}

class MyRoll extends JPanel {
    // override paintComponent in case of custom painting
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out a lot!
Very well organized answer with links for further reading, thanks!