# setting a JFrame background, why this doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set a background to my jFrame, and I'm using this code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DemoBackgroundSwing extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public DemoBackgroundSwing() {
      System.out.println("done");
    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("red.png");
    System.out.println("done");
    loadImage(img);
    System.out.println("done");
  }

  private void loadImage(Image img) {
    try {
      MediaTracker track = new MediaTracker(this);
      track.addImage(img, 0);
      track.waitForID(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    setOpaque(false);
    System.out.println("done");
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo Background Image");
    DemoBackgroundSwing back = new DemoBackgroundSwing();
    System.out.println("done");
    frame.getContentPane().add(back);
    frame.setSize(400, 287);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

when I execute it, in system out I have 5 "done". so this means that all tasks are executed.
I don't understand where's the error. Please Help me!

Comment: Just a quick tip: Use different debug messages in different places.

Comment: It works for me, maybe it can't find your red.png file?

Comment: sorry
it there's not any error. it only doesn't set any background to my frame.

Comment: where if your red.png file placed? is it in the right directory?

Comment: @sbat, I also think that, but what I can change to verify it?

Comment: red.png is in src folder, whith DemoBackgroundSwing.java

Comment: It means both java file and image in same folder(package)? If yes then it should work. Check the width of the loaded image to verify it again.

Comment: @gesualdo try `...createImage(getClass().getResource("red.png"))`.

Comment: @sbat you got it!! Yeahhh! with your last tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the width of loaded image if it's -1 then image is not properly loaded.

```
img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("red.png");
System.out.println(img.getWidth(null)); // check what it prints
```

It's worth reading *Java Tutorial* on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

---

You can try any one based on image location.

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images/c.jpg"));

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/c.png"))

// Read from src/images folder
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/c.png"))
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)

---

**Some Points:**

- call `super.paintComponent(g);` at first line in the overridden `paintComponent()` method.
- Use `ImageIO` instead of `Toolkit` to load the image.
- Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` in case of custom painting.
- Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

  Read more

  - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
  - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
  - [Should we use EventQueue.invokeLater for any GUI update in a Java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541373/should-we-use-eventqueue-invokelater-for-any-gui-update-in-a-java-desktop-applic)

Comment: Thank you I used 

System.out.println(img.getWidth(null)); 

to check what it prints..and the output was -1.

then I modified  
...createImage("red.png");
 in 
...createImage(getClass().getResource("red.png"));

Comment: but it in a folder images under src folder and try options that is mention in the post. Read other points as well.