# JLabel containing an ImageIcon won't repaint

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I'm writing an application that creates a deck of cards in a random order and when a button is pressed moves the top card to the bottom and shows the new top card.  (It's to simulate a Planechase deck to those familiar with Magic: the Gathering.)  When the button is pressed it is properly cycling through the image files, but when I assign an image to a JLabel with an ImageIcon I can't get the JLabel to refresh with the new image.  Here's the code I'm using to refresh

```
    nextCardButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            planechase.topCardIncrement();
            createCardToDisplay();
        }
    });
```

planechase is an instance of a class CardDeck which stores the randomized deck and has several methods to shuffle, change cards, etc.  topCardIncrement() changes the top card to the next in the list.

```
    private void createCardToDisplay()
    {
    cardToDisplay = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()));
    }
```

createCardToDisplay assigns cardToDisplay to an image derived from the folder name of the images and the current file.  cardToDisplay is placed within JPanel contentPanel which is placed within JFrame frame.  I can't figure out the proper way to repaint/revalidate (I'm not quite clear on what the difference is) my GUI to reflect the updated image.  I've confirmed via System.out.println calls that

```
    planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()
```

is updating as it should, so I assume that the JLabel is being reassigned properly.  What is the proper way to redraw this so that it reflects the new ImageIcon?

Comment: Where are the images stored relative to the class?  Have you tried loading the images with `ImageIO.read` which will throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong...

Comment: Have you tried to call repaint() on the JLabel's container?

Comment: In your code example, you are creating a new instance of `cardToDisplay`, but not adding to anything...this could be cause of your problem, but there is no context by which it would be possible to be sure.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: *"What is the proper way to redraw this so that it reflects the new ImageIcon?"* `cardToDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()));` ... but as per my previous comment, there is no context to be sure that this is the correct thing to do in you case...

Comment: Mad, the images are stored MagicMultiplayerApplication\planes\"...".jpg relative to MagicMultiplayerApplication\src\"...".java  The first image displays itself, and the paths for subsequent images are correct, it's just a matter of properly repainting the JPanel.  And Jaco, I have tried repainting the JLabel's container.  Does the label update if I just call createCardToDisplay again? or do I have to set the previous cardToDisplay to some null value?

Comment: If `cardToDisplay` has already been created, you don't want to create it again, just change the current icon using `setIcon` instead...

Comment: You're about to hit another problem.  Resources contained within the "source" package may not be available at runtime (depending on which IDE you use) or won't be accessible via the means you are using now.  They should be loaded using `Class#getResource`

Comment: MadProgrammer, I misunderstood the way in which I gave the JLabel an image.  I used your line 
`cardToDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()));`
and it worked properly.  I will make sure to format my questions better in the future, though.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get images for an example is to hot-link to images listed in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: Have a look at the [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825) or [post2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805191/setting-a-jframe-background-why-this-doesnt-work/24805279#24805279)

Answer (score 1):

The code is ambiguous...

The first thing that jumps out at me is...

```
private void createCardToDisplay()
{
    cardToDisplay = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()));
}
```

This is creating a new instance of `cardToDisplay`, but is it been added anywhere?  Is the previous instance been removed?  There's no context to be certain.

Normally, when you want to change the icon of a `JLabel`, you would simply call `setIcon` on the instance of the `JLabel`...

```
cardToDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(planechase.getFolderName() + "\\" + planechase.displayTopCard()));
```

Because this is a bound field, it will trigger a repaint request automatically.