# Cannot display icon - Uncaught error when fetching image

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, icons, embedded-resource

I want to display another icon instead of the usual java load icon. I have put that into this folder:

[image]

I want to load it over the `getResource()` method.

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MainWindow.class.getResource("house.png")));
```

However, I am getting:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why does `getResource()` not load my picture from my folder? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: What package is the code that has that code line?  What is the 'root' of the Jar?

Comment: Have you tired `resources/house.png` or `/resources/house.png` instead?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The package name of the class `MainWindow` is: `com.CRUDApp.gui`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Using both strings, results in the same `NullPointerException
` as stated above. Is it possible to display the url from `getResources()`?

Comment: Have you tried `/house.png`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thx a lot that works perfectly fine! Please add this as an answer, so that I can accept it!

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805191/setting-a-jframe-background-why-this-doesnt-work/24805279#24805279) for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for an explanation of why @MadProgrammer's comment (`"/house.png"`) worked:

You are using maven. Files in `src/main/resources` become resources on the class path. Ultimately placed at the root of the classpath, with *no* `main/resources`. So you're intuition was correct, initially just using `"house.png"` as the path, as the image is at the root.

What you failed to consider though is where the call is coming from. When you use `Class.getResource`, the call will begin the search from the location of the class, i.e the package where the calling class is located. So for instance if you have something like

```
src
   main
       resources
               house.png
   main
       java
           com
              mypackage
                      CallingClass.class
```

The search will being in `com/mypackage`. So for this path (`"house.png"`) to work, the image would have to be in the `com/mypackage` package, but it's not. It's in the root.

That brings us to the forward slash `/`. That that forward slash ultimately does, is make the search start from the root of the class path. So *with* the forward slash (`"/house.png"`), the search *will* find the image in `src/main/resources`, which ultimately in the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
setIconImage( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("house.png")));
```

or

```
setIconImage( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MainWindow.class.getClassLoader().getResource("house.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы и сборка была корректная, можно использовать вот это:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png")));
```