# Text Box not working properly

Tags: java, applet, jbutton, textfield

I wrote a program for an applet that is supposed to display different text in a text box when you push a button. My program has no errors when I compiled it, but the text box doesn't display correctly. I don't know what is wrong with it. Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class colors{
Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Label label1;
TextField objTextField1; 

public static void main (String args[]){
colors c = new colors();
}
public colors() {
Frame f = new Frame ("Colors");
Button button1 = new Button("Blue");
button1.setBounds(10,305,120,75);
button1.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener1());
Button button2 = new Button("Red");
button2.setBounds(140,305,120,75);
button2.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener2());
Button button3 = new Button("Yellow");
button3.setBounds(270,305,120,75);
button3.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener3());

f.add(button1);
f.add(button2);
f.add(button3);

label1 = new Label("Click a Button to Reveal Text");
label1.setBounds(20,105,200,25);
f.add(label1);


objTextField1 = new TextField("Which Color?", 15);
objTextField1.setBounds(20,75,125,50);
f.add(objTextField1);

f.add(label1);
f.add(objTextField1);

f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setVisible(true);
}
public class MyMouseListener1 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            objTextField1.setText("Blue");
        }
    }
public class MyMouseListener2 extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            objTextField1.setText("Red");
        }
}

public class MyMouseListener3 extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        objTextField1.setText("Yellow");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using [Swing components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) instead of AWT components

Comment: I tested your code and it's working as expected. ?*the text box doesn't display correctly* what do you mean by this line?

Answer (score 2):

When a `Button` is clicked it fires an `ActionEvent`.

You should use an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) instead of a `MouseListener`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...//code that reacts to the action... 
}
```

**AND** don't forget to add

```
button.addActionListener(instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it's working as expected but I have noticed some of the points in your code as mentioned below:

- Use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` instead of `System.exit(0)` and adding `WindowListener` to close the window.
- Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.
- Don't use `null` layout and never use absolute positioning via calling `setBounds()` instead use a proper Layout Manager that suits as per your application design.

  Read more [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)
- Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)  to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

  Read more

  - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
  - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
  - [Should we use EventQueue.invokeLater for any GUI update in a Java desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541373/should-we-use-eventqueue-invokelater-for-any-gui-update-in-a-java-desktop-applic)
- Follow Java Naming convention
- Keep the instance members `private`
- This is already addressed by @TAsk that you should be using `ActionListener` instead of `MouseListener` if you are interested in only `mouseClicked()` method.
- You should be using Swing components instead of AWT components as already mentioned by @peeskillet

Answer (score 1):

To make an applet you should extend **javax.swing.JApplet** class & override **init()** method.

To change the color, you must write your logics in **actionPerformed()** of **ActionListener**. But it's an interface. So, you can make use of **Anonymous Inner class** & implement **actionPerformed()** in it.

So, when you call **addActionListener()** on a **JButton**, I recommend you to do that by using **Anonymous Inner class**. It would be more clear through following code.

My Suggestion: Whenever you write code, always keep **OOD principles** in your mind. This isn't right place to discuss that, but your code has a **Code smell** which is **Duplication in code**.

Below is the best way to do what you want & we're also using **DRY Principle**.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorChanger extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private JButton btnRed;
    private JButton btnGreen;
    private JButton btnBlue;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        btnRed = new JButton("Red");
        btnGreen = new JButton("Green");
        btnBlue = new JButton("Blue");

        this.add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(btnRed);
        mainPanel.add(btnGreen);
        mainPanel.add(btnBlue);

        bindActionEvent(btnRed, Color.RED);
        bindActionEvent(btnGreen, Color.GREEN);
        bindActionEvent(btnBlue, Color.BLUE);

    }

    private void bindActionEvent(JButton b1, Color color) {

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainPanel.setBackground(color);
                //Write setText() for your TextField here.
            }
        });
    }       //END Of Helper Method
}
```