# What's the difference between the 2 ways of showing window in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I am new to Java Swing GUI development. In some sample code, I see Swing window is shown with the `EventQueue.invokeLater()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MainWindow window=new MainWindow();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setVisible(true);                
        }
    });

    System.out.println("main exited");

}
```

But as I tried, I can also show a window without using `EventQueue.invokeLater()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainWindow window=new MainWindow();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);    

    System.out.println("main exited");

}
```

So what's the difference? When should I use each method?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3541425/2240409

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567870/what-does-swingutilities-invokelater-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When invoking code from the main() method you should ALWAYS use the `EventQueue.invokeLater()` because all Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Yes, the code will work 99.99% of the time when creating a simple GUI the other way, but you don't want to waste time debugging a random bug when it doesn't work.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency and Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT and why Swing components should be created on the EDT.

Note, code executed from a Swing listener is invoked from the EDT.

Comment: Like most, if not all, GUI frameworks you should always run the GUI on their EDT, or equivalent.

Comment: @dwnz Indeed. I used to coding for WinForm, and there's similar idea.